# R.utils::withTimeout, works differently on Linux than in Windows

Tags: r, timeout, settimeout

I ran into some problem.

I have a code which I made on Windows, and I now trying to use it on Linux(Ubuntu).

```
Cost.optim_D.kill<- function(x,RunFile,showLogFile,PathToDaisy,ctrldaisy){

tryCatch(R.utils::withTimeout(Cost.optim_D(x,RunFile,showLogFile,PathToDaisy,ctrldaisy),
                              timeout = 60,
                              onTimeout="error"),
         error = function(ex) {

           PID<-system(paste0('pgrep daisy', Sys.getpid()))

           KILL.daisy <- paste0('kill -9 ',PID)

           system(KILL.daisy)

           daisy_new <- paste0("/opt/daisy/bin/daisy", Sys.getpid())

           if(file.exists(daisy_new)){file.remove(daisy_new)}

           return(runif(1,200,1000))
         })}
```

The code functionality to execute an external program and if that program runs longer than 60 seconds, then the withTimeout, throw an error, and the tryCatch, execute a killing process system function.

This function works well on Windows environment, but in Linux, withTimeout doesnt throw the error after the time limit, while the extrenal Program is running.

Comment: What exactly does `Cost.optim_D` do? There is a long list of "Non-Supported Cases" in the `?withTimeout` help page.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I solved the issue with processx library and dropped the withTimeout function