# guarantee timeout with `mgcv::gam`

Tags: r, timeout, try-catch, mgcv

I'm fitting some GAMs with **mgcv** where I need a high `k` value to capture complicated behavior in some cases. But I've noticed that sometimes (some datasets), fitting the GAM takes forever when `k` is high, and it seems like in these cases, I also don't get convergence. I need to try fitting lots of datasets and can't wait three days when I stumble on one of these datasets where it can take forever *and* ultimately fail!

I encountered `R.utils::withTimeout()`, which seemed like a promising tool to ensure I move on if I hit one of these gam time traps, but it's acting inconsistently for me. Below is a printout of running the same script three times consecutively. Note that the first of these three times, the timeout apparently did not happen. I vaguely understand that [there are situations](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/R.utils/issues/74) where `withTimeout` is expected to fail... I'd like to know how I can enforce a hard stop on `mgcv::gam`, potentially with a different tool (I saw a [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60228036/8400969) to the package **processx**).

This looks like a lot but it's exact repetitions; session info below as well. Key point from the code below is that `withTimeout` apparently did nothing the first time (took 30 seconds) and then kicks in each successive time (8 seconds seems close enough to 6).

Thanks!

```
> tictoc::tic()
> set.seed(2) ## simulate some data... 
> dat <- mgcv::gamSim(1
+               , n = 5000
+               , dist = "normal"
+               , scale = 2)
Gu & Wahba 4 term additive model
> b <- mgcv::gam(y ~ s(x0, k = myk) + s(x1, k = myk) + s(x2, k = myk) + s(x3, k = myk)
+          , data = dat)
> summary(b)

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
y ~ s(x0, k = myk) + s(x1, k = myk) + s(x2, k = myk) + s(x3, 
    k = myk)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  7.84735    0.02869   273.5   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
         edf Ref.df       F p-value    
s(x0)  5.057  6.321  87.162  <2e-16 ***
s(x1)  3.739  4.671 813.470  <2e-16 ***
s(x2) 20.716 25.865 354.052  <2e-16 ***
s(x3)  3.298  4.121   1.496   0.197    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.728   Deviance explained =   73%
GCV = 4.1439  Scale est. = 4.1158    n = 5000
> tictoc::toc()
30.418 sec elapsed
>  # just did this script twice; this part takes me 30 seconds
> 
> tmax <- 6
> 
> tictoc::tic()
> gf <-  tryCatch({
+   res <- R.utils::withTimeout({
+     set.seed(2) ## simulate some data... 
+     dat <- mgcv::gamSim(1
+                   , n = 5000
+                   , dist = "normal"
+                   , scale = 2)
+     b <- mgcv::gam(y ~ s(x0, k = myk) + s(x1, k = myk) + s(x2, k = myk) + s(x3, k = myk)
+              , data = dat)
+     summary(b)
+   }, timeout = tmax)
+ }, TimeoutException = function(ex) {
+   message(paste("Timeout before gam fit complete (should take", tmax,  "seconds)"))
+   
+ })
Gu & Wahba 4 term additive model
> tictoc::toc()
30.332 sec elapsed
> myk <- 120
> 
> tictoc::tic()
> set.seed(2) ## simulate some data... 
> dat <- mgcv::gamSim(1
+               , n = 5000
+               , dist = "normal"
+               , scale = 2)
Gu & Wahba 4 term additive model
> b <- mgcv::gam(y ~ s(x0, k = myk) + s(x1, k = myk) + s(x2, k = myk) + s(x3, k = myk)
+          , data = dat)
> summary(b)

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
y ~ s(x0, k = myk) + s(x1, k = myk) + s(x2, k = myk) + s(x3, 
    k = myk)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  7.84735    0.02869   273.5   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
         edf Ref.df       F p-value    
s(x0)  5.057  6.321  87.162  <2e-16 ***
s(x1)  3.739  4.671 813.470  <2e-16 ***
s(x2) 20.716 25.865 354.052  <2e-16 ***
s(x3)  3.298  4.121   1.496   0.197    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.728   Deviance explained =   73%
GCV = 4.1439  Scale est. = 4.1158    n = 5000
> tictoc::toc()
30.415 sec elapsed
>  # just did this script twice; this part takes me 30 seconds
> 
> # I expect the next part to take 6 seconds based on tmax.
> # dpeending on n and k, it either does, or it can take WAYYY longer. How can I 
> # guarantee 6 seconds.
> tmax <- 6
> 
> tictoc::tic()
> gf <-  tryCatch({
+   res <- R.utils::withTimeout({
+     set.seed(2) ## simulate some data... 
+     dat <- mgcv::gamSim(1
+                   , n = 5000
+                   , dist = "normal"
+                   , scale = 2)
+     b <- mgcv::gam(y ~ s(x0, k = myk) + s(x1, k = myk) + s(x2, k = myk) + s(x3, k = myk)
+              , data = dat)
+     summary(b)
+   }, timeout = tmax)
+ }, TimeoutException = function(ex) {
+   message(paste("Timeout before gam fit complete (should take", tmax,  "seconds)"))
+   
+ })
Gu & Wahba 4 term additive model
Timeout before gam fit complete (should take 6 seconds)
> tictoc::toc()
8.112 sec elapsed
> # Test timeout with mgcv::gam
> myk <- 120
> 
> tictoc::tic()
> set.seed(2) ## simulate some data... 
> dat <- mgcv::gamSim(1
+               , n = 5000
+               , dist = "normal"
+               , scale = 2)
Gu & Wahba 4 term additive model
> b <- mgcv::gam(y ~ s(x0, k = myk) + s(x1, k = myk) + s(x2, k = myk) + s(x3, k = myk)
+          , data = dat)
> summary(b)

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
y ~ s(x0, k = myk) + s(x1, k = myk) + s(x2, k = myk) + s(x3, 
    k = myk)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  7.84735    0.02869   273.5   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
         edf Ref.df       F p-value    
s(x0)  5.057  6.321  87.162  <2e-16 ***
s(x1)  3.739  4.671 813.470  <2e-16 ***
s(x2) 20.716 25.865 354.052  <2e-16 ***
s(x3)  3.298  4.121   1.496   0.197    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.728   Deviance explained =   73%
GCV = 4.1439  Scale est. = 4.1158    n = 5000
> tictoc::toc()
30.318 sec elapsed
>  # just did this script twice; this part takes me 30 seconds
> 
> # I expect the next part to take 6 seconds based on tmax.
> # dpeending on n and k, it either does, or it can take WAYYY longer. How can I 
> # guarantee 6 seconds.
> tmax <- 6
> 
> tictoc::tic()
> gf <-  tryCatch({
+   res <- R.utils::withTimeout({
+     set.seed(2) ## simulate some data... 
+     dat <- mgcv::gamSim(1
+                   , n = 5000
+                   , dist = "normal"
+                   , scale = 2)
+     b <- mgcv::gam(y ~ s(x0, k = myk) + s(x1, k = myk) + s(x2, k = myk) + s(x3, k = myk)
+              , data = dat)
+     summary(b)
+   }, timeout = tmax)
+ }, TimeoutException = function(ex) {
+   message(paste("Timeout before gam fit complete (should take", tmax,  "seconds)"))
+   
+ })
Gu & Wahba 4 term additive model
Timeout before gam fit complete (should take 6 seconds)
> tictoc::toc()
8.04 sec elapsed
```

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Ventura 13.2.1

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.10          compiler_4.2.3       pillar_1.8.1         R.methodsS3_1.8.2    R.utils_2.12.2       tools_4.2.3          mvnfast_0.2.8        digest_0.6.31        evaluate_0.20        lubridate_1.9.2     
[11] lifecycle_1.0.3      tibble_3.2.1         nlme_3.1-162         gtable_0.3.2         lattice_0.20-45      timechange_0.2.0     mgcv_1.8-42          pkgconfig_2.0.3      rlang_1.1.0          Matrix_1.5-3        
[21] cli_3.6.0            rstudioapi_0.14      patchwork_1.1.2.9000 yaml_2.3.7           parallel_4.2.3       xfun_0.37            fastmap_1.1.1        gratia_0.8.1         knitr_1.42           stringr_1.5.0       
[31] furrr_0.3.1          dplyr_1.1.0          generics_0.1.3       vctrs_0.6.0          globals_0.16.2       tictoc_1.1           grid_4.2.3           tidyselect_1.2.0     glue_1.6.2           listenv_0.9.0       
[41] R6_2.5.1             fansi_1.0.4          parallelly_1.34.0    rmarkdown_2.20       tidyr_1.3.0          purrr_1.0.1          ggplot2_3.4.1        magrittr_2.0.3       htmltools_0.5.4      scales_1.2.1        
[51] codetools_0.2-19     splines_4.2.3        colorspace_2.1-0     future_1.32.0        utf8_1.2.3           stringi_1.7.12       munsell_0.5.0        R.oo_1.25.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the R process hangs in C code that doesn't check for interrupts, then you might be out of luck with `setTimeLimit` (or utilities based on that).  `setSessionTimeLimit` also relies on checks for interrupts, so setting a timeout that way, on the R process itself or on an R subprocess, could likewise fail.

In that case, you can set a system-level timeout on the R (sub)process using, e.g., the `timeout` command on Linux.  As an example:

```c
/* startInfiniteLoop.c */
#include <Rinternals.h>
SEXP startInfiniteLoop(void) {
    while (1) ;
    return R_NilValue;
}
```

```r
## startInfiniteLoop.R
tools::Rcmd(c("SHLIB", "startInfiniteLoop.c"))
dyn.load("startInfiniteLoop.so")
.Call("startInfiniteLoop")
```

This R process hangs and you need to manually kill it:

```bash
$ R -f startInfiniteLoop.R
```

This one also hangs but is killed automatically after 20 seconds:

```bash
$ timeout 20 R -f startInfiniteLoop.R
```

You can invoke `timeout` from an R process using `system2`, so that timeouts on R subprocesses are specified entirely in your R script, if that's what you prefer:

```r
system2("timeout", c("20", "R", "-f", "startInfiniteLoop.R"))
```

Obviously, your use case is more complicated.  You probably need to pass variables to and from the subprocess, and so on, but maybe you can fill in those details yourself.